# How can i get every month first day array value using PHP

Tags: php

Date wise data's are return my array. i want every month date one array set

```
Array
(
    [2014/09/01 13:47:54] => 73206
    [2014/09/02 11:00:01] => 73205
    [2014/10/01 14:00:07] => 73206
    [2014/10/03 15:00:01] => 73207
    [2014/11/01 18:00:02] => 73208
    [2014/11/05 02:00:01] => 73209
    [2014/12/01 10:00:01] => 73210
    [2014/12/02 12:00:02] => 73209
    [2014/12/04 13:00:02] => 73208
    [2014/01/01 23:00:02] => 73209
    [2014/01/08 09:00:02] => 73210
    [2014/02/01 10:00:03] => 73211
    [2014/02/19 11:00:02] => 73210
)
```

My Expectation Like this

```
[2014/09/01 13:47:54] => 73206
[2014/10/01 14:00:07] => 73206
[2014/11/01 18:00:02] => 73208
[2014/12/01 10:00:01] => 73210
[2014/01/01 23:00:02] => 73209
[2014/02/01 10:00:03] => 73211
```

Comment: Will you elaborate please?

Comment: What is the problem that you are facing ? Could you please give explain the things that you have tried ?

Comment: you want 17,18 19 like this

Comment: Every month first array value have to know using php.

Comment: @ Saravana Kumar try this...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
try this
<?php
$data=Array ( "2014-09-17 13:47:54" => "73206", "2014-09-17 11:00:01" => "73205",
 "2014-10-17 14:00:07" => "73206", 
 "2014-10-17 15:00:01" => "73207",
 "2014-11-17 18:00:02" => "73208",
 "2014-11-18 02:00:01" => "73209",
 "2014-12-18 10:00:01" => "73210",
 "2014-12-18 12:00:02" => "73209",
 "2014-12-18 13:00:02" => "73208", 
 "2014-01-18 23:00:02" => "73209",
 "2014-01-19 09:00:02" => "73210",
 "2014-02-19 10:00:03" => "73211", "2014-02-19 11:00:02" => "73210" );
echo '<pre>';
print_r($data);
foreach ($data as $key => $value) {
    $getdate=date('d',strtotime($key));
    $getmonth=date('M',strtotime($key));
    echo 'Date=>'.$getdate.'  Month=>'.$getmonth;
    //echo $getdate=date('d-m-y',strtotime(''));
    echo '<br>';
}

?>
```

your answer

```
    <?php
    $data=Array ( "2014/09/01 13:47:54" => "73206", "2014/09/02 11:00:01" => "73205",
     "2014/10/01 14:00:07" => "73206", 
     "2014/10/17 15:00:01" => "73207",
     "2014/10/03 15:00:01" => "73208",
     "2014/11/01 18:00:02" => "73209",
     "2014/11/05 02:00:01" => "73210",
     "2014/12/01 10:00:01" => "73209",
     "2014/12/18 13:00:02" => "73208", 
     "2014/12/02 12:00:02" => "73209",
     "2014/12/04 13:00:02" => "73210",
     "2014/01/01 23:00:02" => "73211", "2014/01/08 09:00:02" => "73210" );
    echo '<pre>';
    print_r($data);
    foreach ($data as $key => $value) {
      $getdate=date('d',strtotime($key));
        if($getdate=='01' || $getdate=='1'){
        echo '['.$key.']'.'=>'.$value; 
        }
        echo '<br>';
    }

    ?>
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for helping me, But my expectation [2014/09/01 13:47:54] => 73206
[2014/10/01 14:00:07] => 73206
[2014/11/01 18:00:02] => 73208
[2014/12/01 10:00:01] => 73210
[2014/01/01 23:00:02] => 73209
[2014/02/01 10:00:03] => 73211 Pls guide me how can i get

Comment: i am submit your answer